# java regex for finding number then text not number then underscore

Tags: java, regex

I need to do a `string.indexOf(text)` on a text string to search for the pattern

```
1. some text or 
2. some other text or 
3. some yet another text, etc
```

(a number, a dot and some text)

such that I avoid picking the substrings

```
1. _________ and 
2.__________ and 
3.__________
```

(a number followed or not by a space followed by a variable number of underscore characters)

I tried this

```
public static int indexOf(Pattern pattern, String s) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    return matcher.find() ? matcher.start() : -1;
}

indexOf(Pattern.compile("["+i+"\\.][^_]+"), text);
```

but does not work.

The following is a sample example

1. Some of the websites don't even list the prices-like they're afraid to specify how much the things cost.
2. We find adapted computers, talking boards that speak the words, push-button systems, and even devices that work with blinks or head
   nods.

   1. ---
   2. ---
   3. ---
   4. ---
   5. ---
   6. ---

Comment: A sample input and output will be easier for us to understand your need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to determine if there are underscores following the number, you have to use lookahead, or the pattern will just match everything up until the underscore. Try this:

```
indexOf(Pattern.compile(i+"\\.(?!\\s*_).*"), text);
```

It looks for the number 'i', followed by a period. Then it looks ahead for any underscores, and if they're found, the match fails. If there are no underscores, it matches all of the characters that follow.